# redux-observable, injecting dependency for a dependency

Tags: dependency-injection, redux-observable

I'm using redux-observable and have two dependencies.  The second dependency is also dependent on the first depedency.

StoreService is dependent on the ConfigService and this is the class for the StoreService

```
const StoreService = (http, Config) => {
    return {
        getStores: () => {
            const syncGalaxyStoresUrl = Config.syncGalaxyUrl + Config.storesEndPoint;
            return Observable.fromPromise(axios.get(syncGalaxyStoresUrl));
        }
    };
};
```

This is how I declare my dependencies

```
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic, {
    dependencies: {
        http: axios,
        Config: configParams,            
        StoreService: StoreService,
    }
});
```

How do I inject the second dependency Config and http into the StoreService dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a closure would work

```
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic, {
  dependencies: {
      http: axios,
      Config: configParams,            
      StoreService: () => StoreService(axios, Config),
  }
});
```

Another way would be just to utilize the fact that `StoreService` is a factory that itself captures them in a closure. Then in your epics you don't have to do `StoreService().getStores()`, they can just do `storeService.getStores()`

```
const createStoreService = (http, Config) => {
  return {
      getStores: () => {
          const syncGalaxyStoresUrl = Config.syncGalaxyUrl + Config.storesEndPoint;
          return Observable.fromPromise(axios.get(syncGalaxyStoresUrl));
      }
  };
};

const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic, {
  dependencies: {
      http: axios,
      Config: configParams,            
      storeService: createStoreService(axios, Config)
  }
});
```

Comment: I just realized this was a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116207/redux-observable-dependencies-one-service-dependent-on-another